# How to fix choppy video playback of local flv file in adobe air application?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, video, air, flv

I have made a application that plays videos that are stored in a assets folder of the air application but when ever I run it on an hp slate the videos are really choppy. Is there a way to preload the video or does it have to do with the processing power? the videos are 1.72mb or smaller. They are flv format and they auto play when that application is started. I am using flash builder.
Thanks if advance for you help,
Justin

Comment: Have you tried different video encodings? I wonder if the H.264 f4v would be any better. I've not seen any video on the HP Slate so I have no idea what it's capable of as far as Flash video playback.

Comment: It is not at full screen its using the <s:VideoPlayer with a if statement to get the source to know witch video to play. example (if (this is true) { videoPlayer.source = "assets/videos/step1video.flv"; } I not sure what you mean by flvplayback. Not sure how to use that yet will look into it and get back as soon as i understand.

Comment: Ok so something else that i found out. It's only jumpy when i use flash.display.StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE; to set the stage that the video is running in to full screen size. Anyone have any ideas? Is there another way to set the size of the screen to full that i could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Air, you also have the possibility of not using the fullscreen-mode. You can set the windowChrome attribute of the app.xml to none and the showStatusBar attribute of the WindowedApplication false. Then you just have scale the whole app manually to the screen resolution.
It's kinda ugly, but depending on your needs (e.g. kiosk-application) that'll be just fine.